# Working with Slim Framework and htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On


# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ searchPage.php?crs_category=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Now the way Slim Framework works is that all requests are redirected to `index.php`, where `index.php` route the requested path to its render page.

Hence, typing `category/business` will not rewrite the url of `searchPage.php?crs_category=business` but instead redirect to `index.php` where Slim Framework will throw a page not found since there is no path `category/:name` defined to be routed.

My problem is working out this scenario, where I would like all requests except `category/NAME` to be redirect to `index.php`.

I would also appreciate when someone types `searchPage.php?crs_category=business` for that url to be rewritten to category/business with ideally a 301 status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RewriteCond to apply some conditions to the following rules. In your case, something like:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ searchPage.php?crs_category=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/searchPage.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I added the "L" switch on the first match, so it will not continue parsing rewrite rules for current request.

On the next request, the RewriteCond line says "only apply the following rule if the URI does NOT start with **searchPage.php**".

Comment: thank you. could this also be done the other way auround lets say someone tries to access searchPage.php?crs_category=Microsoft it should rewrite to category/microsoft and let seo know that its that format to be used? Thank yo

Comment: Simple answer is, yes, you can do what you want. Not sure about the "let seo know" part, but that's not probably part of the question so I will just ignore it.