# Slim framework htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

I'm using Slim framework, the htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

So all requests go to index.php where the paths are then routed. I have some category pages on my site like:

```
/category/1/apples
/category/2/pears
/category/3/oranges
```

I want those categories to also be accessible by going to the following:

```
/apples
/pears
/oranges
```

Please help me edit the htaccess to achieve this.

I found this question which almost answers it for me but not quite: [Working with Slim Framework and htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907600/working-with-slim-framework-and-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess file look good. The Slim Framrwork is responsible for further routing.

Example `routes.php`

```
<?php

use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

$app->get('/category/{id}/{name}', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args) 
   return $response->withJson($args);
});

$app->get('/apples', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args) 
   return $response->write('apples');
});

$app->get('/pears', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args) 
   return $response->write('pears');
});

$app->get('/oranges', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args) 
   return $response->write('oranges');
});
```

If you need more generic routes then try this:

```
$app->get('/category/{id}/{name}', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args) 
   return $response->withJson($args);
});

$app->get('/{category}', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args) 
   return $response->withJson($args);
});
```